# HTML5 section headings

Tags: html, header

Say I have a section of content on my page, i.e.:

**Heading 1**
Some content

What would be the best way to represent this using HTML5?

```
<section>
    <header>
        <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    </header>
    <p>Some content</p>
</section>
```

Or would it be:

```
<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</section>
```

I guess I'm a bit confused whether the header tag is required here or if it's superfluous. I've been reading the specifications and I haven't seen anything address this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `<header>` was made to replace the traditional `<div id="header">` - [the usual place for banners, logos and stuff above the website..](http://www.sitepoint.com/5-things-i-love-about-html5-2/#fbid=8iS0wthp7DA)

in your case, your "header" is more of a title for the following content. a heading+paragraph pair is suitable for that.

```
<section>
    <h1>Heading 1</h1>
    <p>Some content</p>
</section>
```

Comment: You only realls need to use ´header´ when you have more in the header than a single ´h´ element, e.g. if it also contains an image or something like that.